# Yii CActiveDataProvider UNION ALL

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I would like how to use `UNION ALL` on `CActiveDataProvider` `criteria`.

Table Example:

```
ID    NAME
1     John
```

Query Example:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
  UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM users
```

Response:

```
ID    NAME
1     John
1     John
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sems that `CDbCriteria` doesn't handle the `UNION ALL`

Instead you could use the `CSqlDataProvider` class

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM tbl_user UNION ALL SELECT * FROM tbl_user ';
$dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
    'totalItemCount'=>$count,
    'sort'=>array(
        'attributes'=>array(
             'id', 'username', 'email',
        ),
    ),
    'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>10,
    ),
));
// $dataProvider->getData() will return a list of arrays.
```

Comment: @Gunnit Yeah because `CSqlDataProvider` doesn't have an attribute named `criteria` (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSqlDataProvider)

Comment: any idea how i could use it in the search of the model ?

Comment: @Gunnit Do you really need `CSqlDataProvider`? (`CActiveDataProvider` wouldn't be more suited for you?)

Comment: How to use this with search criteria? Ex. In CActiveDataProvider, you can pass the $criteria. Is there any similar method with this one?